# How to detect the window width change?

Tags: reactjs

I have different pages of content to apply, depending on the width of the window.
I did it with the condition:

```js
{window.innerWidth > 575 ? <Big component> : <Little component>}
```

It works well but not if you reduce the page without reload manually.

I tried to implements useEffect on it, but I don't find how to trigger it by the widow.width change.
Please, could you help me ?

This is my code:

```js
 const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(window.innerWidth);

 useEffect(() => {
   setWindowSize(window.innerWidth);
 });

 return (
    ... 
      {windowSize > 575 ?  <Big component> : <Little component>}
    ...
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `innerWidth` would not change on window resize. You would need to reload the page to update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without registering an event listener, you cannot achieve updating of `innerWidth`.

Here is a way to do this with an event listener:

```
const handleWindowResize = useCallback(event => {
    setWindowSize(window.innerWidth);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    };
}, [handleWindowResize]);
```

You can add and remove the event in the `useEffect` hook.

You can create a `memoized` handler using `useCallback` hook.

This is called a `callback pattern`.

In this we are simply setting the state using the updated innerWidth, its best to use the `callback pattern` and register the event listeners only on initial mount.

If you register the events in `useEffect` hook, the listeners reference along with its lexical scope is being used by the event listener but a new function is created with updated closure on each new render preventing the handler from accessing the updated state.

More on `useCallback` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and [here](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/72/Creating-a-Reusable-Window-Event-Listener-with-useEffect-and-useCallback).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.onresize` You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

```js
function reportWindowSize() {
    console.log(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth)
}

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

For your use case. You can use `window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize)` inside your hook.

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
useEffect(() => {
    function reportWindowSize() {
        setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
        console.log(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth)
    }
    // Trigger this function on resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize)
    //  Cleanup for componentWillUnmount
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Utsav and MDN docs for debouncing this is my custom hook I created for my application

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";


interface MediaObj {
  isMobile: boolean;
  isTablet: boolean;
  isLaptop: boolean;
  isDesktop: boolean;
};

//upper limit (BP) for each device. based off Bootstrap breakpoints
const mobileBP = 768; //sm
const tabletBP = 992;  //md 
const laptopBP = 1200  //lg
const dekstopBP = 1400; //xlg

const defaultValues= {
  isMobile: window.innerWidth <= mobileBP ? true : false,
  isTablet: (window.innerWidth > mobileBP && window.innerWidth <= tabletBP) ? true : false,
  isLaptop: (window.innerWidth > tabletBP && window.innerWidth <= laptopBP) ? true : false,
  isDesktop: (window.innerWidth > laptopBP) ? true : false,
}

const useDetectResize = () => {
  const [mediaType, setMediaType] = useState<MediaObj>(defaultValues);
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState<{w:number, h:number}>({w: window.innerWidth, h: window.innerHeight});
  let timeout = false;

  //register callback so our function isn't instantiated on each re-render.
  const handleWindowResize = useCallback((timeout:any) => {
    // clear the timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    // debounce getDimensions function ever N ms
    timeout = setTimeout(getDimensions, 1000);

    //store width/height and mediaState 
    function getDimensions(){
      let width = window.innerWidth;
      let height = window.innerHeight;
      setWindowDimensions(currState => currState = {w:width, h: height});
      console.log('Width Saved!: ', width);

      let mediaTypes = {
        isMobile: window.innerWidth <= mobileBP ? true : false,
        isTablet: (window.innerWidth > mobileBP && window.innerWidth <= tabletBP) ? true : false,
        isLaptop: (window.innerWidth > tabletBP && window.innerWidth <= laptopBP) ? true : false,
        isDesktop: (window.innerWidth > laptopBP) ? true : false,
      }

      setMediaType(currState => currState = mediaTypes);
    }

}, []); 

  useEffect(() => {
    // window.resize event listener will call handleWindowResize() whenever screen width is adjusted.
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
  },[])
  
  return{
    isMobile: mediaType.isMobile,
    isTablet: mediaType.isTablet,
    isLaptop: mediaType.isLaptop,
    isDesktop: mediaType.isDesktop,
    windowDimensions
  }
}

export default useDetectResize;
```

then I call it in my components like so

```
  const { windowDimensions, isMobile, isTablet, isLaptop, isDesktop } = useDetectResize();
```